# How can i send a message in a existing conversation established by two normal Lync user?

Tags: lync, ucma, lync-server-2010

### Here is the scenario of my question:

- There is a Two-party call between Roger and Regina, they are common Lync user. and they have send several IMs to each other. Now I would like to send a message(like a notification ) to them in their conversation window, but not open a new conversation window which contain the message I send to them.

### Here is my effort:

- First, I read Michael Greenlee’s blog “Invisible OCS conference participants”, then I try to achieve my goal in that way. But it seems the Result is not what I want.

  1. This is “group conversation ”, but not conversation just between two normal Lync user;
  2. when the invisible application endpoint send a message in the “group conversation window”, it will not invisible now.

  So, can anybody give me some advice, I really appreciate that.

BR

Rainbow Zhou

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. There is a direct message flow between two Lync endpoints, you cannot touch that.

For a third endpoint (be it a user or an application) to be able to communicate with your two users, you will need a conference. And then still, messages will show as being send from your application.

You can hide the application from the participant list, or you could BackToBack both Roger and Regina in the conference so they do not even know theyre in one. The application can impersonate any name/sipuri and send messages pretending to be someone else.

Your main problem, however, will be getting "in between" the conversation between Roger and Regina. You could use MSPL scripts to redirect SIP Invites to your endpoint, then use your endpoint to create a conference, and invite the second participant. This is not trivial, and depending on why and how you want to send a "notification", probably completely overkill. If in any way possible, I would look for a different way to notify your users.

One option could be to use the Lync Client SDK to create an application that interacts with the client's Lync instance. Send messages to your application and have it try to inject them into the conversation. This would require the app to be installed on each client PC though, and you will need to think of a way to push messages to your application.

Comment: > Thank you for your answer, Willem. _I really appreciate that._ And totally agree with you. We can not achieve this goal using UCMA. 
> So this days I am research Lync-Server 2010 SDK, it seems we can operate the SIP package by the managed sip application. Then I am wandering **is there any chance we can achieve our goal by using managed sip application on Lync server?**
But until now, I am Just reading the Lync-Server 2010 SDK and try to do some test on the “Request”. Still do not have any clue. 
> So could you please give me some advice about my new try? _Really thanks for your help._